# Push O/R data updates to Windows Store clients

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, azure, windows-store-apps, sqldependency

I am developing a multi-user Windows Store client app. The app's main screen displays data that can be updated by users at any time. Any changes made by a user needs to be pushed onto all clients in order to update the data displayed on the main screens of all the other users.

Would Azure's Notification Hubs apply to my scenario?  The demos I've seen so far only show the pushing of "toast" notifications.  In my case, I need to push notifications to client application code for programmatic processing rather than for direct display to the user.

My client app is programmed in a way that requires an object/relational mapping tool sitting between it and the database.  It appears that Azure's Mobile Services includes support for Entity Framework and so can facilitate this.  Is it possible to leverage Notification Hubs to achieve the goal of keeping all clients updated with the latest database changes?  If so, then how would I accomplish each event in the following sequence?

1. Inform the mobile service that the database has changed.
2. Notify all the clients about the changes.
3. Materialize the changes on each client as objects via the O/R mapper.

Comment: The best way to notify a client app data has changed is push notifications.  I thought ef7 on store and phone apps would only work with SQLite.

Comment: @KenTucker Do you mean push notifications in general or [Notification Hubs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/notification-hubs/) specifically? Regarding EF7, I reread [the info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx) and yes, initially at least, that will unfortunately be the case.

Comment: push notifications in general